# Bayesian approach for setting upper limit

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, statistics

In the presentation by [Cowan](https://www.pp.rhul.ac.uk/%7Ecowan/stat/stat_11.pdf), on slide 18, he explains the baseyian approach of setting upper limit in parameter estimation.[image]

What I didn't get is the formula written. Bayes's theorem is like $P(a|b) \propto P(b|a)*P(a)$. While here in the slide, it is written as $P(\theta|x) \propto P(\theta|x)*P(\theta)$. Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don’t see anywhere on the slide where it is written like that

Comment: @Dale In slide, it is written in terms of Likelihood while I wrote in terms of probability. Like as it is given in : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability.  (L(parameter=fixed_value|data) = P(data|parameter=fixed_value))

Comment: He uses weird notation. See slide 50 here https://www.pp.rhul.ac.uk/~cowan/stat/stat_3.pdf